# Configure Cannon p200 ink jet printer in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, software-installation

I have a **cannon p200 ink jet printer** and I am having problems with setting it up with Ubuntu 12.04. The Ubuntu driver database does not provide the driver for this series of printer.

I searched and downloaded a `tar.gz` driver, converted it to `.deb` using `alien`, installed it through Ubuntu software center.(installation just was like extraction of the files to rpm)

now the problem is I have no clue of how to use it. I tried to set up printer (after installing ) but cannot see any change on the process before and after installing the driver. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In linux the `lpr` Command is used to submit the print jobs with few arguments such as

```
lpr [ -E ] [ -H server[:port] ] [ -U username ] [ -P destination[/instance] ] 
    [ -# num-copies [ -h ] [ -l ] [ -m ] [ -o option[=value] ] [ -p] [ -q ] 
    [ -r ] [ -C/J/T title ] [ file(s) ]
```

You can do `man lpr` for more info.

In order to verify if the printer is installed or to check what is the default printer, use the following command.

```
lpr -s #this will list the pritner operational status
lpr -d #this will list the default printer.
```

there is graphical web-interface used by **CUPS** as well to manage the printers in GUI. You may have to install it, therefore type

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cups cups-client lpr`

Open firefox or other browser and goto  `http://localhost:631`

make sure you add the user for **cups** by `sudo adduser <username> lpadmin` in order  to login into the CUPS Admin portal.

You can read more information about it @ http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ulpr.htm

I hope this helps. Good Luck